# Marquee is scrolling very fast or something is wrong

Tags: css, html

this is my website http://divyajyoti.net but marquee is not working properly i tried to change scrollamount to 0, 1,2,3,4 and it was still not working properly please see the code and help me what to do thanks

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>:: Welcome to Divya Jyoti Industries Limited ::</title>
<style type="text/css"><!--
body {
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
-->
</style>
<link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
<table background="images/spacer.gif" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="960"><!--DWLayoutTable-->
<tbody>
    <tr> 
        <td colspan="3" height="13" valign="top">
        <table background="images/home_02.jpg" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="959"><!--DWLayoutTable-->
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td height="13" valign="top" width="959"><img alt="" height="13" src="images/home_02.jpg" width="959" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </td>
        <td width="1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" valign="top" width="314">
        <table background="images/spacer.gif" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="314"><!--DWLayoutTable-->
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td height="177" valign="top" width="314"><img alt="" border="0" height="177" src="images/home_04.jpg" usemap="#Map2" width="314" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" height="120" valign="top">
        <table background="images/home_05.jpg" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="645"><!--DWLayoutTable-->
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td height="120" valign="top" width="645">
                    <div class="navigation"><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>|<a class="main" href="about_us.html">About Us</a>|<a class="main" href="product.html"> Products</a>|<a class="main" href="member.html">Member</a>|<a class="main" href="investors.html">Investors</a>|<a class="main" href="career.html">Career</a>|<a class="main" href="contact.html">Contact</a></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" valign="top" width="594">
        <table bgcolor="#FBF1D8" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="594"><!--DWLayoutTable-->
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td height="224" valign="top" width="594">
                    <div><object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0" height="219" width="594"><param name="movie" value="homebanner.swf" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><embed height="219" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" quality="high" src="homebanner.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="594"></embed></object></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2" valign="top" width="51">
        <table background="images/spacer.gif" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="51"><!--DWLayoutTable-->
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td height="224" valign="top" width="51"><img alt="" height="224" src="images/home_07.jpg" width="51" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </td>
        <td height="57"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" valign="top">
        <table background="images/home_08.jpg" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="314"><!--DWLayoutTable-->
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="marquee" height="544" valign="top" width="314"><marquee behavior="alternate" direction="down" height="540" scrollamount="4" style="height: 540px;">
                    <p><a href="1999-00.jpg"><img border="1" height="169" src="images/1999-00.jpg" style="margin-bottom:10px" width="225" /></a><br />
                    3rd Highest Capacity utilization in Soya Industry in year 1999-2000</p>

                    <p><a href="2001-02.jpg"><img border="1" height="169" src="images/2001-02.jpg" style="margin-bottom:10px" width="225" /></a><br />
                    2nd Highest Capacity utilization in Soya Industry in year 2001-2002</p>

                    <p><a href="2002-03.jpg"><img border="1" height="169" src="images/2002-03.jpg" style="margin-bottom:10px" width="225" /></a><br />
                    3rd Highest Capacity utilization in Soya Industry in year 2002-2003</p>

                    <p><a href="2003-04.jpg"><img border="1" height="169" src="images/2003-04.jpg" style="margin-bottom:10px" width="225" /></a><br />
                    3rd Highest Capacity utilization in Soya Industry in year 2003-2004</p>

                    <p><a href="2004-05.jpg"><img border="1" height="169" src="images/2004-05.jpg" style="margin-bottom:10px" width="225" /></a><br />
                    3rd Highest Capacity utilization in Soya Industry in year 2004-2005</p>
                    </marquee></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </td>
        <td height="167"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" height="377" valign="top">
        <table background="images/home_09.jpg" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="645"><!--DWLayoutTable-->
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td height="377" valign="top" width="645">
                    <div class="style2">
                    <p class="style3"><strong>Welcome to the DJ Parivaar!</strong><br />
                    <strong>Welcome to the Soy Shed!</strong></p>

                    <p>We are Central India&#39;s trusted Soybean processing Industry engaged in processing Soybean to extract valuable Soy Oil and Soymeal along with other valuable by-products like Lecithin, Acid Oil and Soy Deo Distillate.</p>

                    <p>With the experience of more than a decade in the processing of Soybean, we at Divya Jyoti master the art of growth fixation. In the year 1995, we started with a set-up of 300 TPD Solvent Extraction Plant with a vision to establish long term business relations with esteemed companies by supplying them crude Soy oil &amp; Soy meal. Today Divya Jyoti has a 700 TPD Solvent extraction plant and a 100 TPD state of the art Refinery. Our growth rate is a combined team effort and is result of technically sound infrastructure, ultra-modern machinery, hi-tech laboratory, skilled manpower, hygienic storage space &amp; above all the dedication and experience to meet the deadlines with the assurance of quality.</p>

                    <p>Reliability, flexibility, competitive pricing and prompt services have been pillars of company&rsquo;s reputation and success. This is also reflected in the high level of customer satisfaction, which is driving&nbsp;force behind the company&rsquo;s growth.</p>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" height="61" valign="top">
        <table background="images/spacer.gif" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="959"><!--DWLayoutTable-->
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td height="61" valign="top" width="959"><img border="0" height="61" src="images/home_10.jpg" usemap="#Map" width="959" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: The `<marquee>` element was intended to scroll just text, not blocks of HTML. In any case it is now obsolete and might be removed from the browsers at any time. For these reasons you should look at animating your block with CSS and JavaScript instead. See the [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<marquee direction="down" height="540" scrollamount="4" style="max-height:540px;">
```